# Add Activity on top of existing backstack when launched from notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, back-stack

I have Activity A, B and C
C is launched from notification.

But, backstack gets cleared when launched from notifications. I know about TaskStackBuilder and specifying the back intents, but that will be a hardcoded back stack.

If C is launched after A, then back press should go back to A
If C is launched after A>B, then back press should go back to B and then got back to A on second back press.

How do I preserve the current back stack and add on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Set all the possible target activities' launchMode in your Manifest.xml to either "singleTop" or "singleTask" depending of your need:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

The different launch modes are well explained [here](https://medium.com/@iammert/android-launchmode-visualized-8843fc833dbe).

Comment: 1)Does it preserve the already existing activity stack? I am launching the activity from notification.
2) Should I declare the target activity as singletop?

Comment: I have set my target activity to singleTask. Doesn't help. Android clears the back stack when you launch an activity from notification.

Comment: I a defining my pendingintent as :
 PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, 0, notifyIntent, 0
            );
where notifyIntent is my target activity intent